# Switch individual MOSFETs connected across lithium-ion cell for passive balancing

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver, nmos, cell-balancing, cell

[image]

I am working on a passive cell balancing circuit using N-MOSFET. The cell voltage will be monitored by the micro-controller and it can also generate corresponding logic level signal according to over charge for a particular cell. I want to build a control circuit that can individually switch the N-MOSFET connected in series so that the a particular cell which is overcharged is discharged via resistor and the overcharge cell is balanced. How can I build a drive circuit for the N-MOSFET?

Comment: What happened to your previous post on this subject - why did you delete it? You know, if you really want help it's a two way thing.

Comment: What did your research on the subject reveal?

Comment: @Andy aka i actually made a wrong circuit in my last post

Comment: @winny do i need to make some kind of bootstrap circuit for switching the high side mosfet

Comment: OK, why are you not considering pre-built circuits for this?

Comment: i am actually  curious to learn how to switch the transistor for  passive balancing  the series connected cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing to remember about this arrangement is that each FET gate switching voltage is (e.g. 0V = OFF, 10V = ON :  10V being right for most MOSFETs) ... but relative to its own source voltage.

So for Q1. source = 3 * Vcell, gate = source + 0 (off) or source + 10V (on).

Your task is to generate each such individual gate voltage.

There are many ways to do this but the simplest is to use a chip designed for the job as Tomas suggests.

Comment: thanks for your response,do i need to make some kind of bootstrap circuit for switching high side mosfet

Comment: That's one way and there are "high side driver" ICs  to help, but the classic bootstrap requires regular switching (like PWM) to keep the bootstrap capacitor charged. Feasible, because you don't need the FET ON 100% of the time for balancing.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered pre-made ICs like BQ77915 by TI? Simple IC with many battery protection features.

Comment: thanks for your response,i have read the data sheet of the ic that you have suggested but i am trying to make a passive cell balancing circuit using discrete components